# How to create function with input is 2D array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a 2D array that defined as

```
int P[5][10];
for (int i=0;i<N;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<L;j++)
    {
        if(random()>0.5)
            P[i][j]=1;
        else
            P[i][j]=0;
    }
}
```

I want to make a function with input is P. The function allows us show the value of P. How to defined that function. I tried such as

```
void show_P(int P[][], int numcols,int numrows)
```

However, it is wrong. Could you help me fix it? Thanks

Comment: Don't use 2D arrays. Use 1D arrays, perhaps encapsulating them in some class which has member functions to access or modify them.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch: Do you have any simpe way? Thanks

Comment: Declare a 1D array or vector, and use `a[i*width+j]` instead of `a[i][j]`

Comment: Just for beginner, I used 2D.

Comment: You should avoid 2D arrays. It is very likely that you'll get confused. And there is no need for them.

Comment: You could always search the net for a proper answer. One I could easily found is here, on stackoverflow:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/8767247/1432385

Comment: @LucaciAndrei It is too bad that the selected and most up-voted answer is full of wrong / misleading statements. Otherwise I would have used it to close this as duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to restrict the arguments to 5 by 10 2D arrays, you can pass by reference like this:

```
void show_P(int (&P)[5][10])
```

This will fail for any other type of array. If you want the function to work for other sizes, you can make it a template.

```
template <size_t N, size_t M>
void show_P(int (&P)[N][M])
```

Comment: Is it safety way? That means we don't worry about memory problem. Someone suggest to me using 2D points array. However, I think your suggestion is very simple. Thanks

Comment: @user8430 This has type safety, as mentioned in the answer. A pointer to pointer doesn't have that.

Comment: Good knowledge. Thank you.

Comment: Can your way apply for returning 2D array? That means if I want to write a function to return 2D array, can I apply template <size_t N, size_t M>
void set_P(int (&P)[N][M])

Comment: @user8430 That isn't "returning a 2D array", but modifying an input parameter. Yes, you can kind of do that, but only by setting the elements of the array. Arrays are not assignable or copyable like, say, `int`s or `double`s are.

Comment: Could you show to me one way to apply the work "return 2D array"?Thanks

Comment: @user8430 There isn't a way to do that, because arrays are not copyable.

Answer (score 1):

You could just change it to:

```
void show_P(int** P, int numcols, int numrows)
```

Passing 2D array always using the pointer.

Hope this will help.

Comment: This does not solve the OP's problem - you can't pass a 2D array of int as an `int **`.

Answer (score 1):

Or using the std::array

```
void printArray(array<array<int,2>,3>& arr)
{
  for (auto x : arr)
  {
    for (auto y : x)
    {
      cout << y << endl;
    }
  }
}

int main()
{
  array<array<int,2>,3> arr{{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}}};
  arr[0][1] = 5;
  printArray(arr);
}
```

would give you:

1

5

2

3

3

4

Answer (score 0):

```
void print( int (&ref)[5][10]) {

for( auto &lm: ref) // get the first array from the multidimensional array and initialize lm with it 
    for( auto &elem: lm) // get the first element from lm 
        std::cout << elem << " "; // print the element 

}
```

This only works with an array with dimensions as P i.e,   **[5][10]**

Comment: I have made 'lm' a reference because if we don't then lm will not be a reference to an array but rather have a type of int * which is not that we want it to be.

Answer (score -1):

```
N=5;
L=10;    
void show_P( int ( &P )[N][L] )
```